# Error creating pdf/a with latex

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to create pdf/a through latex. I inserted in my tex file the package:

```
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
```

with the option `a-1b` but I got error:

```
pdfTeX error (ext5): cannot open file for embedding ...eam attr{/N 4} file{sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm}
\pdfobjcompresslevel > 0 requires \pdfminorversion > 4. Object streams disabled now.
```

I don't really know what does it mean

Answer (score 5):

This is a color profile.  Printers need them to correctly print  color pdfs.  There are a number of profiles on the net.

You can find this file here:  https://github.com/bencomp/pdfx-ext/blob/master/sRGBIEC1966-2.1.icm

Comment: where I should copy it after having downloaded?

Comment: The simplest way is to put it in your working directory, where the .tex file is

Comment: Ok the error has gone...but I got another error: Option clash for package hyperref. \def. What does it mean?

Comment: you probably call hyperref with some options that conflict with those provided by pdfx package.  Try removing the options from `\usepackage[OPTIONS]{hyperref}`

Comment: the option in hyperref are the metadata of pdf file. if I remove it, how can I have metadata?

Comment: use `\hypersetup` after calling the packages.